# I'm trying to define a function inside of a loop using onclick event, but it doesn't work like I expect. What should I do differently?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am trying to add border to the div in html page using javascript. I cant seem to do it using  onclick event. This is my javascript:

```
var attacker = document.getElementsByClassName('attacker');
for (var i = 0; i < attacker.length; i++) {
attacker[i].onclick = function() {
    attacker[i].style.border = "3px solid blue";
}};
```

And here is my html:

```
<div  class="attacker">
  <img src="img/'.$race2.'/'.$units2[$i].'.jpg" />
  <div class="hp"></div>
</div>
```

When i change add border by entering attacker[0].style.border = "3px solid blue";
directly into javascript it is working, but when i use onclick event it says that i cannot set property of undefined.
Any idea where i went wrong?

Comment: Can you set up an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `i` is not being closed over, so the `.onclick` function will always use `i` as the length of the `.attacker` list + 1.  There are several solutions, but my favorite is to iterate over the node list with `.forEach` so that the closure is automatic:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('attacker'),
function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.style.border = "3px solid blue";
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution also works, but i am choosing Zlatan's bacause it looks better, and it is more readable. Thank you.

Comment: @happy_fist his solution still relies on the `onclick` attribute, which is bad!  Event attributes do not use the standard event registration model.  If you like, you can replace the `Array.prototype.forEach` loop with a standard `for` loop too; the rest of my solution will work with it.  I just prefer iteration (actually think it is more readable myself) than looping.  If readability is a concern, a JavaScript library like jQuery can do what I have done in a lot less code.

Comment: so there is a difference between onclick event and event listener that listens for click event?

Comment: @happy_fist you can only have one `onclick`, but you can bind multiple event listeners to `click`

Answer (score 1):

A solution is made here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/XjKEj/

Use `this` in your anonymous function, instead of `attacker[i]`, because it is not available under that function scope.